# Many to many in secondary table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations

I have a class:

```
@SecondaryTables(
    {
        @SecondaryTable(
            name = ReaEconomicAgentCatalog.TABLE_NAME
            , pkJoinColumns = 
            {
                @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(
                    name = "rea_economic_agent_catalog_id"
                    , referencedColumnName = "eav_entity_id"
                )
            }
        )
    }
)
public class ReaEconomicAgentCatalog 
    extends EavEntity
    implements HasZonedAvailabilityPeriod
    , Serializable
{

...

    @JoinTable(
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
            name = "rea_economic_resource_kind_id"
            , referencedColumnName = "rea_economic_resource_kind_id"
        )
        , joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
            name = "rea_economic_agent_catalog_id"
            , referencedColumnName = "rea_economic_agent_catalog_id"
        )
        , name = "rea_economic_agent_catalog_resources"
    )
    @ManyToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY
        , targetEntity = ReaEconomicResourceKind.class
    )
    private Set<ReaEconomicResourceKind> reaEconomicResourceKinds;
```

We're getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(rea_economic_agent_catalog_id) of com.corbettcode.rea.model.policy.ReaEconomicResourceKind.reaEconomicResourceKinds referencing com.corbettcode.rea.model.accountability.agent.ReaEconomicAgentCatalog not mapped to a single property
    at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1740)
```

What we know so far is that 'rea_economic_agent_catalog_id' is not in the property list of the class which is why the exception is thrown.

This is code that worked in eclipselink and is being migrated to hibernate. I know this is probably something simple, but we just cannot figure it out. Any help would greatly appreciated.

Tried running unit tests. Expecting not to fail.

Answer (score 0):

We figured it out...needed to use the same value as the referencedColumnName in the @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).